# Deleting messages from Firestore JAVA

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore

I want to delete last message from my firestore.

```
  public void delete_messages (Integer delete_message){
        FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
           db.collection("messages").limitToLast(delete_message)
            .delete()
            .addOnSuccessListener (aVoid -> Log.d("Kasowanie", "DocumentSnapshot successfully deleted!"))
            .addOnFailureListener (e ->  Log.w("Kasowanie", "Error deleting document", e));
}
```

Where is Error ?

EDIT. I want delete last message for example 
delete_messages(10) -- deleting last 10 messages.

Firebase structure 
Collection --messages 
Documents structure
-login
-time
-text

[image: Structure Base]

Comment: Please post your database structure and explain what is problem.

Comment: What kind of error are you refering to? Is there anything not working with the given code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your own answer is mostly the way to do it. The biggest thing to realize is that you can only write/delete a document in Firestore if you know its complete path. So Firestore doesn't support something like DELETE queries, where you send a query to Firestore. Instead you have to execute the query in your code, and then delete the result, as the code in [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59695452/209103) does.

The thing I noticed is that the actual delete call can a lot simpler than in your answer though, since you can easily get a `DocumentReference` from the `DocumentSnapshot` in your completion listener.

So something like:

```
public void delete_messages(Integer quantity) {
    FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    db.collection("messages").orderBy("time", Query.Direction.DESCENDING).limit(quantity)
            .get()
            .addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                        document.getReference().delete()
                            .addOnSuccessListener (aVoid -> Log.d("Kasowanie", "DocumentSnapshot successfully deleted!"))
                            .addOnFailureListener (e ->  Log.w("Kasowanie", "Error deleting document", e));
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.e("ERROR", "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
                }
            });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

MY SOLUTION

```
public void delete_message(String id, FirebaseFirestore db){
        db.collection("messages").document(id)
                .delete()
                .addOnSuccessListener (aVoid -> Log.d("Kasowanie", "DocumentSnapshot successfully deleted!"))
                .addOnFailureListener (e ->  Log.w("Kasowanie", "Error deleting document", e));
    }

    public void delete_messages(Integer quantity) {
        FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        db.collection("messages").orderBy("time", Query.Direction.DESCENDING).limit(quantity)
                .get()
                .addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                            Log.d("Document_id", document.getId() + " => " + document.getData());
                            delete_message(document.getId(), db);
                        }
                    } else {
                        Log.e("ERROR", "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
                    }
                });
    }
```

But maybe there is a simpler way?